# How can I count the number of $n$ digit positive integers without a specific digit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Came across the Kempner Series and was doing a little reading.

The proof that the Kempner Series is bounded by 80 requires the fact that the number of $n$ digit positive integers without the digit 9 in them is $8(9^{n-1})$.

I bet there is a combinatorial way to show this, but I can't think of it.  I thought of proving it with induction, but that seems like overkill.

How can I prove this to myself?

Comment: Maybe you should try proving it with induction and then decide if that's overkill, you might want to also post that theoretical proof here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**
In a $n$ digit number, you cannot use $9$ in all positions, and cannot use $0$ in the first position.

- how many choices for first position?
- how many choices for each of the other positions?
- how many total choices?

Comment: UGH. So obvious.  I should have paid more attention on my combinatorics lectures.

Comment: @DemetriP :) lol...